# Vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, & $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, field-theory

Are there any useful applications of vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and finite fields?  For example, are vector spaces over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ used for anything?  How about fields larger than $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, right?

Comment: Vote to close: "useful applications" is hopelessly vague. The notions that you are challenging have well known applications within mathematics.

Comment: @user4894 Yes, thanks.  I corrected it.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not challenging anything.  I'm trying to learn about the "well known applications" to which you allude.  They are not well known to me.

Comment: "Are there any useful applications of ...?" is a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, why stop at fields? You can have "vector spaces" over rings, though we usually call them modules over rings. These are ubiquitous in mathematics: for instance the [Serre-Swan theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre-Swan+theorem) identifies certain modules with vector bundles over a space.

If you're looking for applications of vector spaces over *fields* (other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), specifically, then these often come up in algebraic topology. For instance, this paper discusses the [rational cohomology](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Fung.pdf) of Lie groups, and also cohomology with coefficients in various finite fields. If you google "rational homology" or "rational cohomology" you'll find plenty more examples.

Answer (score 2):

The classic [*Galois Theory*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197041) by Emil Artin uses linear algebra as a foundation.

The number fields that appear in algebraic number theory are by definition finite-dimensional vector spaces over the rationals.

Finite fields are used in [error detection and correction](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/error-correcting-codes-and-finite-fields-9780192690678?cc=br&lang=en&).

Answer (score 2):

Also in algebraic geometry, the tangent and cotangent spaces at a point of a variety are vectors spaces over the residue field at the point.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially computer graphics (so think Pixar, Disney, computer games) all use rational point geometry (ie vector spaces over $Q$).

The same goes for 3d printing software.

Is this the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: I would argue that computer graphics do not use vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, instead it is using floating point arithmetic. (for example, depending on the precision that is being used, you might have something like $0.25 \cdot 0.50 \mapsto 0.13$)